# Symfony 4 Mailer [ gmail ] takes too long

Tags: php, symfony4, fosuserbundle, swiftmailer, mailer

I recently implemented implemented `fos/user-bundle`, the user can only connect to the website only if he receives a confirmation mail.
So I implemented the mail mailing like below in the `env` file

```
MAILER_URL=gmail://user:password@localhost?encryption=tls&auth_mode=oauth
```

in the `swiftMailer.yaml` i implemented this:

```
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

**If too many users send an email at the same time it will take up to `1 minute` to get the mail**

any suggestions on how to reduce the waiting time?

Comment: Sending emails is something that should as a general rule of thumb be done with a message queue.

Comment: You're sending email using your gmail account? That's something I suggest to change as Gmail impose rate limiting. You should use 3rd party email sender for that...